# WSO2 Governance Registry nightly builds?

Tags: wso2, wadl

Are there nightly builds of the WSO2 GREG somewhere? I'm behind a customer's proxy which has a weird configuration, building from source is getting very difficult. My specific need is to test the new WADL support, which doesn't look available in the 4.5.0 distribution. On the other hand, is there any alternative way to test the new WADL support without building the GREG from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to evaluate nightly build the location given is correct. But WADL support has been removed from WSO2 4.5.1 distribution at the moment. So this binary pack does not include it.

Comment: Thank you Shelan. Is there a roadmap yet for WADL support in future releases?

Comment: Yes. It is in our road map and we will add it in the future releases when we make it more usable and up to the expected level of quality.